# Getting a string inside a string from regex

Tags: java, regex

My String is something like this :

```
str1="&lt;accountName&gt;THOMAS M PINCHBECK&lt;/accountName&gt;";
```

I am trying to use regex to get the name : THOMAS M PINCHBECK

What I tried is :

```
str2= str1.matches("&lt;accountName&gt;"+"(.*)"+"&lt;/accountName&gt;");
```

But this didn't work out. Any help would be appreciated..!!

Comment: Do you specifically require Regex to do this? And how do you decide on what part of String you want to extract.

Comment: @Prateek : I need the text between this : &lt;accountName&gt; , &lt;/accountName&gt;

Comment: Why would you use `matches`? As you probably realise it returns `boolean`, not `String`. Instead you can use Pattern and Matcher classes. First you create Pattern with regex, then Matcher with your input, next call `find` or `matches` on Matcher object and your result will be in group(1).

Comment: @rahul888 In that case why not get indexes of these two strings and use substring method to get everything in between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matches(...)` method of `String` returns `boolean`, not `String`. You can fix it like this:

```
String str = "&lt;accountName&gt;THOMAS M PINCHBECK&lt;/accountName&gt;"+
    "&lt;accountName&gt;Hello world&lt;/accountName&gt;"+
    "&lt;accountName&gt;Quick brown fox&lt;/accountName&gt;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&lt;accountName&gt;([^&]*)&lt;/accountName&gt;");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/o6Litg)

Comment: The `.*` being greedy wouldn't prevent the regex from matching, it would initially match to the end of the string but then it would backtrack until the regex could match.  Using `[^&]*` is more efficient, but this answer doesn't adequately explain why the OP's version isn't working.

Comment: @F.J I see what's happening there now - I edited to remove the incorrect explanation.

Comment: Yeah the current version looks correct, I didn't know enough about Java's regex methods to figure out what was wrong but it did seem like some issue around how he was interpreting the return value.

Comment: thanks did work like a charm this..!! but what if this condition comes multiple time in a string with different names..?

Comment: You can keep calling `m.find()` multiple times to obtain the remaining matches.

Comment: so u meant m.find() inside a m.find()..??

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Chat for a few mins

Comment: @rahul888 Take a look at the edit, I added more code for multiple matches for the demo as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Can we chat for a minute..?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I think this fails when my name contains some symbol like &amp; or &amp;&amp;

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#replaceFirst`:

```
String str = "&lt;accountName&gt;THOMAS M PINCHBECK&lt;/accountName&gt;";

String repl = str.replaceFirst("^&lt;accountName&gt;([^&]+).*$", "$1");
//=> THOMAS M PINCHBECK
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=&gt;).*?(?=&lt;)
```